# board support package contituents , requirements and provisions. SPI based device

Tags: linux, spi, bsp

I am developing a BSP (board Support Package) for a Linux board. The board contains a device which runs on SPI. I would likw your suggestions on weather I should provide a device specific driver with the BSP or should a SPI driver be sufficient.

Also if some device has user mode driver instead of kernel mode. Then this user mode driver will be part of BSP?

Answer (score 0):

Imho it is good to provide with the BSP a device specific driver as your driver knows the specifics of the Hw component you provide or otherwise you need to share the SPI slave Hw details so that someone else can develop the driver for the particular SPI device.

Only Kernel mode artifacts could be part of BSP.